# Hiding multiple elements when CSS changes

Tags: jquery

I have a few buttons I am using as tags. I would like to check whether the tags are visible and if ALL tags are hidden, then hide the clear selection link. 
MY HTML IS:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 cols">
      <div id="tags">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default usertitle-tag hide-tag tg-btns">x &nbsp;&nbsp;Usertitle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default comments-tag hide-tag tg-btns">x &nbsp;&nbsp;Comments</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default topics-tag hide-tag tg-btns">x &nbsp;&nbsp;Topics</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default login-tag hide-tag tg-btns">x &nbsp;&nbsp;Login</button>
    </div>
       <a href="#" class="cancel clear">Clear selection</a>
        </div> <!--/.col-xs-12-->
```

I have tried this with jquery but the clear selection is still visible. Where am I going worng?

```
$('.hide-tag').each(function(){
     if ( $(this).css('display') == 'none'){
       $(".clear").hide();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the visibility to true if at least one `hide-tag` is visible like

```
$(".clear").toggle($('.hide-tag').is(':visible'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is(":visible")` in jquery which will return `true` if the element is visible

Try like

```
$(this).is(":visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hide-tag:visible').size() > 0 ? $(".clear").show() : $(".clear").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements , this function will hide the clear tag in case no button is visible.

Check it out.

```
    function checkForClearBtnDisplay()
    {
        clearBtnVisible=0;          //BY DEFAULT CLEAR TAG VISIBILITY SET AS FALSE

        $('#tags button').each(function(){

                if($(this).is(':visible'))
                {
                    clearBtnVisible=1;  
                }                       
        });

        if(clearBtnVisible==0)
        {
            //HIDE THE CLEAR TAG IN CASE NO BUTTON IS VISIBLE
            $('.clear').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.clear').show();
        }
    }   

</script>
```